# Next with testing library and Jest : error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'firstName')

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test a basic form with Jest and testing library. I keep getting the same error on Jest which I don't understand why: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'firstName')

Here is the code for the form I am trying to test on the component:

```
import React, { useState, useReducer } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Input from "../../components/Input";
import NextButton from "../../components/Button/Next";
import { UserReducer, DefaultUser } from "./user-reducer";
import { stepOneValidate } from "./validation";


const StepOne = ({ step, setStep, user, setUser }) => {
  console.log(user);

  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
  // const [user, setUser] = useReducer(UserReducer, DefaultUser);

  // handle onchange
  const handleUser = ({ target }) => {
    setUser({
      type: "UPDATE_STEPONE_INFO",
      payload: { [target.name]: target.value },
    });
  };
  const handleContinue = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const errors = stepOneValidate(user);
    setErrors(errors);
    if (Object.keys(errors).length > 0) return;
    setStep(step + 1);
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleContinue}>
      <h4 className="font-bold text-lg leading-title mb-6">Step {step + 1}</h4>

      <Input
        type="text"
        name="firstName"
        data-testid="firstName"
        label="First name"
        onChange={(e) => handleUser(e)}
        error={errors.firstName}
        value={user.firstName}
      />
      <Input
        type="text"
        name="lastName"
        data-testid="lastName"
        label="Last name"
        onChange={(e) => handleUser(e)}
        error={errors.lastName}
        value={user.lastName}
      />
      <Input
        type="number"
        label="Age"
        name="age"
        data-testid="age"
        onChange={(e) => handleUser(e)}
        error={errors.age}
        value={user.age}
      />
      <NextButton data-testid="submit" type="submit">
        Next
      </NextButton>
    </form>
  );
};
StepOne.propTypes = {
  step: PropTypes.number,
  setStep: PropTypes.func,
  user: PropTypes.object,
  setUser: PropTypes.func,
};

export default StepOne;
```

So here basically Jest does not like the value value={user.lastName} and keeps erroring out.

Here is the Jest test file:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import StepOne from "../pages/register-user/step-one";
import { expect, test } from "@jest/globals";

describe("<StepOne />", () => {
 
  test("render name and text input", () => {
    render(<StepOne />);

    const nameInput = screen.getByTestId("firstName");
    expect(nameInput).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(nameInput).toHaveAttribute("type", "text");
  });
});
```

I cannot figure out why Jest gives out that error. Once I remove the value={user.firstName} from the page, Jest is able to test the page.

The form needs that value in order to preserve the form data so I cannot remove it eventhough that's what I tried.

I tried setting up again Jest to see if it is a setup issue perhaps but it's not.

I tried other methods with testing library to see if it is the right utility but that did not help.

I can actually test a component button but Jest says, anything with this value={user.firstName) I do not like. I just cannot figure it out please if there is some help with this. I actually have not worked with Jest too much.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if something went wrong when you copied your component code here but I noticed that the state that is managing `user` is commented out.

Regardless, this is not a "testing" issue. When you reference properties of an object that doesn't exist yet, you will get that error hence the error wording `properties of undefined`. If you set your `user`'s initial state to an empty object, it should solve the problem but the values you reference will still be `undefined`, i.e `user` is defined but `user.lastName` etc will be `undefined`.

To get around that, it is good practice to initialize state with default values (preferably from the same type that the state is supposed to store). I'm not what else your reducer supposed to do and whether you actually need it, but if I were to use `useState`, I would initialize the `user` state like so:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({
  // I would normally initialize state that manages numbers with a default value of number type
  // but inputs manage all values as strings by default so I made that an empty string as well
  age: '',
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
})
```